# I am using batch file to execute Oracle procedure but getting error

Tags: oracle, batch-file

I am using a batch file to call a procedure, but getting error:

> ORA-12560: TNS=Protocol Adapter Error.

Below is the batch file I am using. Also see the attached screen shot.

```
@echo off
set user_name=DSAGILE
set password=mpno2015#02zwcr

set net_SID=FRDSTT1D
(
    echo @ProcedureToExecute.sql
    echo exit
) | sqlplus -s %user_name%/%password%@%net_SID%
pause
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltlnx.png)

Comment: What do you get if you do `tnsping FRDSTT1D`?

Comment: Why do you not use `sqlplus -s %user_name%/%password%@%net_SID% @ProcedureToExecute.sql`?

Comment: I run the command but ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your environment correctly, eg

```
C:\temp\oh>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Feb 7 10:55:42 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name: ^C
C:\temp\oh>set ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\product\12.2.0.1

C:\temp\oh>set ORACLE_SID=db122

C:\temp\oh>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Feb 7 10:56:05 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri Feb 02 2018 15:00:42 +08:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```